# Configure ActiveMQ plugin without activemq.xml and spring

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I want to configure an ActiveMQ broker to use a jaas authentication plugin. I know this can be done using xml-configuration using something like below

```
<broker useJmx="false" persistent="false" xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" populateJMSXUserID="true">
    <plugins>
        <!--  use JAAS to authenticate using the login.config file on the classpath to configure JAAS -->
        <jaasAuthenticationPlugin configuration="activemq-domain" />
    </plugins>
</broker>
```

. But afaik this also requires me to bring spring-stuff to the classpath, something i would like to avoid. Can the broker plugins be started in some other ways

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `BrokerService` to start an activemq broker from within Java code. 
You can call a variety of configuration methods on the respective object. See http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-embed-a-broker-inside-a-connection.html for more detail. The site has an example for the jaas plugin.

Comment: You can also search for the usage of plugins in the ActiveMQ unit tests, this will give you many examples to work from.